# Ucce 8.5 ICM - How to extract SIP Header in ICM script

Tags: cisco, sip

We are collecting the sip headers from CVP Ops console. We are setting variables using the

```
mid(call.sipheader,Startlocation,Length)
```

If the string length changes, the values are not correct. Is there a way to extract using the sipheader varible directly by name?  For example:

```
call.sipheader.someheader
```